# Concurrent message processing in RabbitMQ consumer

Tags: multithreading, azure, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ so please excuse me if my question sound trivial. I want to publish message on RabbitMQ which will be processed by RabbitMQ consumer.

My consumer machine is a multi core machine (preferably worker role on azure). But QueueBasicConsumer pushes one message at a time. How can I program to utilize all core where I can process multiple message concurrently.

1. One solution could be to open multiple channels in multiple threads and then process message over there. But in this case how will i decide the number of threads.
2. Another approach could be to read message on main thread and then create task and pass message to this task. In this case I will have to stop consuming messages in case there are many message (after a threshold) already in progress. Not sure how could this be implemented.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This thread may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531072/rabbitmq-by-example-multiple-threads-channels-and-queues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second option sounds much more reasonable - consume on a single channel and spawn multiple tasks to handle the messages. To implement concurrency control, you could use a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) to control the number of tasks in flight. Before starting a task, you would wait for the semaphore to become available, and after a task has finished, it would signal the semaphore to allow other tasks to run.

You haven't specified you language/technology stack of choice, but whatever you do - try to utilise a thread pool instead of creating and managing threads yourself. In .NET, that would mean using [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) to process messages asynchronously.

Example C# code:

```
using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(MaxMessages))
{
    while (true)
    {
        var args = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
        semaphore.Wait();
        Task.Run(() => ProcessMessage(args))
            .ContinueWith(() => semaphore.Release());
    }
}
```

Instead of controlling the concurrency level yourself, you might find it easier to enable explicit ACK control on the channel, and use [RabbitMQ Consumer Prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) to set the maximum number of unacknowledged messages. This way, you will never receive more messages than you wanted at once.