# Share RabbitMQ channel between multiple python processes

Tags: python, rabbitmq, multiprocessing, pika

I want to share the `BlockingChannel` across multiple python process.
In order to send 
`basic_ack` from other python process.

How to share the `BlockingChannel` across multiple python processes.

Following is the code:

```
self.__connection__ = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
self.__channel__ = self.__connection__.channel()
```

I have tried to dump using `pickle` but it doenst allow to dump Channel and give error `can't pickle select.epoll objects`
using the follwoing code

```
filepath = "temp/" + "merger_channel.sav"
pickle.dump(self.__channel__, open(filepath, 'wb'))
```

**GOAL:**

Goal is to send `basic_ack` from channel from other python processes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an antipattern to share a channel between multiple threads and it's quite unlikely you will manage to share it between processes.

The rule of thumb is 1 `connection` per process and 1 `channel` per thread.

You can read more in regard of this matter at the following links:

1. [13 common RabbitMQ mistakes](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2018-01-19-part4-rabbitmq-13-common-errors.html)
2. [RabbitMQ best practices](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2017-12-29-part1-rabbitmq-best-practice.html)
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531072/rabbitmq-by-example-multiple-threads-channels-and-queues?answertab=votes#tab-top) SO thread gives an in depth analysis in regards of RabbitMQ and concurrent consumption

If you want to pair message consumption together with multiprocessing, the usual pattern is to let the main process receive the messages, deliver their payload to a pool of worker processes and acknowledge them once they are done.

Simple example using `pika.BlockingChannel` and `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```
def ack_message(channel, delivery_tag, _future):
    """Called once the message has been processed.
    Acknowledge the message to RabbitMQ.
    """
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=delivery_tag)

for message in channel.consume(queue='example'):
    method, properties, body = message

    future = pool.submit(process_message, body)
    # use partial to pass channel and ack_tag to callback function
    ack_message_callback = functools.partial(ack_message, channel, method.delivery_tag)
    future.add_done_callback(ack_message_callback)
```

The above loop will endlessly consume messages from the `example` queue and submit them to the pool of processes. You can control how many messages to process concurrently via RabbitMQ [consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) parameter. Check [`pika.basic_qos`](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingChannel.basic_qos) to see how to do it in Python.

Comment: Yes. right. The channel is not guaranteed to be concurrency.

Comment: I want to hold the message and send ack from api in irder to receive next message. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.